# Recreating distribution by estimating parameters

Tags: r, parameters, distribution

Let's say I have a distribution that I would like to approximate:

```
dist1<-sample(c(rbeta((tasks-tasks/2),10,1,1), rbeta((tasks/2),1,10,1)),100)
dist2<-rbeta(n,10,10,1)
combined<-dist1+dist2[1]
```

Let's assume that I do not know how `'combined'` was constructed.
How can I estimate the parameters of `'combined'` to obtain the shape values for a beta distribution?

In other words I would like to generate a beta distribution using `rbeta()` that mimics `'combined'`.

Comment: So you want to do [parameter estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory)

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: See `fitdistr` in the `MASS` package  ...